# How to zip a folder in Azure-Data-Lake-Storage gen2?

Tags: databricks, azure-data-lake

I am looking for a solution to zip all the files stored in an adls folder and then want to move it to another adls folder.

I am trying to do this operation in databricks.

Note: I am not allowed to mount adls data to dbfs.

Comment: Could you please add what you have tried so far and errors and blockers if any?